# Выравнивания для listview

Tags: android

Уважаемые `android`-прогеры джедай нужен ваш совет-помощь,

Есть ли возможность в обычном `listview` в котором содержится строка (состоящая из двух слов) сделать выравнивание для 1 из слов в строке, или для такого вывода лучше использовать `gridview`?

Comment: какую выравнивание вы хотите? можете объяснить и дать код как вы это делаете?

Comment: Ответом на ваш вопрос будет да, возможно. Если вам нужен более детальный ответ, с примером, то напишите проблему и попытки решения в виде кода.

Answer (score 1):

Разместите LinearLayout в ориентации gorizontal поставте в него два TextView, если нужно добавте "вес" для ровного распределения места, и выравнивайте их отдельно и инфлейтите это дело в ListView.